# Simple application of survival function of noncentral chi square distribution

Tags: statistics

Im looking for a new(ish) paper that is an application (with a simple setup and background) of the survival function of a noncentral (or with noncentrality parameter 0) chi square distribution. I want the given probability to have some applied science meaning, i.e., approximating P(chi square pdf > x) with the CLT is relevant. Horgan and Murphy (2013) and Seri (2015) have examples of this in energy detection but I'm looking for something else but similar to the idea.